# Gray navigation item buttons in EKEventEditViewController when global tint is set

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, eventkit, tintcolor

I was trying to use an `EKEventEditViewController` in my app, which has a global tint (set here:[image: Where to set global tint]

However, when the app is run, the `EKEventEditViewController`'s navigation buttons are gray, as if they were disabled:

[image: What is happening to me]

The buttons still work, I just don't want them to be gray like this.

My storyboard:

[image: My storyboard]

The popover to present the event edit view controller (it's presented when you click the "Add to my Calendar" button):

[image: The popover]

The code for presenting the `EKEventEditViewController` is as follows:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UINavigationController *nav = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"theIdentifier"];
    SODPopoverViewController *controller = nav.childViewControllers[0];

    controller.startDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];

    self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:nav];
    self.popover.delegate = self;
    [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].frame inView:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].superview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Any idea what's going on?

### Miscellaneous information:

- I am using iOS 7.1
- I am using XCode 5
- I am using storyboards
- This is **not** the complete program, just a demo.
- SOD stands for Stack Overflow Demo

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** the buttons are gray even without the global tint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was messing around with the problem a little bit more, and noticed that it *wasn't* actually the global tint, but the fact that it was being presented modally. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20134694/really-strange-app-color-behavior) answered mine: the solution is setting `self.window.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal;`